# Maximally entangled states of a qutrit system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

How do I construct a qutrit system and then a maximally entangled state for a qutrit system?

Comment: Why the question is closed? What clarity the closer wants? The question is clear from the title alone!

Comment: I remember there exist various measures of entanglement, but we give unique definition to maximally entangled state.

Comment: @kludg this can also be closed as a homework-style question.  Basically question of the genre “please do the work for me” are historically not received very well.

Comment: If so, this is interesting homework for me. I don't know the answer.

Comment: @kludg but this is not a homework site and your proposed edit make the question *more* homework-like.

Comment: I see no sign of homework. This is rather interesting question, I think.

Comment: @kludg what part of "this is interesting homework for me" is not homework?  There is no sign that the OP did any work on this, there is no conceptual knot identified: the OP is just asking for someone else to do the work.

Comment: There is nothing homework-like in the question. It was closed without a reason.The question is of course poor and could be better, for example explain what is maximally entangled state, but this is not a sufficient reason to close the question.

Comment: @kludg IMHO the question is really not clear. As the answer points out, it is not clear at all what a maximally entangled state means here. To talk about entanglement, we need to have a notion of subsystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that when you say "construct" you mean "mathematically represent" rather than "physically construct" (which is a much more complicated question).

A [qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit) has two basis states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ and its general state is

$\alpha |0 \rangle + \beta |1 \rangle$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers such that $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2=1$.

Similarly a [qutrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qutrit) has three basis states $|0\rangle$, $|1 \rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ and its general state is

$\alpha |0 \rangle + \beta |1 \rangle + \gamma |2 \rangle$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are complex numbers such that $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 + |\gamma|^2=1$.

Not sure what you mean by a "maximally entangled state" for a qutrit. A qutrit is a single quantum system - to create entanglement you need an ensemble of two or more systems. With what are you entangling your qutrit ? If you want to create a maximally entangled state of *two* qutrits then I think the extension of [Bell states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state) from qubits to qutrits should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: What are these |0>,|1>,|2> basis states?

Comment: @MaazKhan They are just arbitrary labels for the three possible states that can be outcomes of the measurement of a qutrit, in the same way as $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are labels for the the two possible states that can result from the measurement of a qubit. What they *physically* represent depends on how the qutrit is physically implemented, which is something I know very little about.